# How to eager load same column names using Laravel's eloquent?

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent, orm, eager-loading

I ran back to back into this problem once again while I am trying to generate an API response

The very basic code is something like that:

```
// This works, but its incomplete
Car::with(['user:id,name', 'factory', 'producer'])

// This does not work, ambiguous column names SQL error
Car::with(['user:id,name', 'factory:id,name', 'producer'])
```

I feel like this is a bug or place for improvement in Eloquent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found out how to do this quickly.

Firstly I found that this code works:

```
 Car::with(['user' => function($q) {
     $q->selectRaw(DB::raw("users.id, users.name"));
 }, 'factory' => function($q) {
     $q->selectRaw(DB::raw("factories.id, factories.name"));
 }, 'producer'])
```

Then I wanted to remove the raw part of the builder and I wondered if this works in a similar way so I ended up with:

```
Car::with(['user:users.id,users.name', 'factory:factories.id,factories.name', 'producer'])
```

Works like a charm